# {"error":"Bad Request"} response from custom php

Tags: php

I'm completely new to php, and was hoping to get some assistance on understanding this custom script on our server as our full-time dev ended up going on a sudden leave of absence. When visiting our webpage I am getting the error:

```
{"error":"Bad Request"}
```

And our dev seems to have created a router.php file that seems to be redirecting all the traffic and thus displaying this error. I'm having a hard time trying to understand where this error is coming from and how I could further troubleshoot it. But here's the code within the router.php

```
<?php

use util\HttpStatus;

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

function module($request)
{
    $request = ltrim($request, '/');

    $qp = strpos($request, '?');
    if ($qp > 0) {
        $request = substr($request, 0, $qp);
    }
    $tokens = explode('/', $request);
    return $tokens[0];
}


function __run($request)
{
    $modules = [
        "dashboard",
        "inventory",
        "branches",
        "promotions",
        "feeds",
        "websites",
        "leads",
        "slfleads",
        "events",
        "media",
        "notify",
        "callback"
    ];

    $requestedModule = module($request);

    if(in_array($requestedModule, $modules)){
        file_exists("../services/$requestedModule/_boot.php")
            ? require ("../services/$requestedModule/_boot.php")
            : require ("../$requestedModule/_boot.php");
        _boot();
    } else {
        _blameAndDie();
    }
}

function _blameAndDie($reason = null)
{
    http_response_code(HttpStatus::BAD_REQUEST);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo ($reason === null)
        ? '{"error":"Bad Request"}'
        : '{"error":"Bad Request","reason":"' . $reason . '"}';
    die();
}

function _blockAndDie($reason = null)
{
    http_response_code(HttpStatus::UNAUTHORIZED);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo ($reason === null)
        ? '{"error":"Forbidden"}'
        : '{"error":"Forbidden","reason":"' . $reason . '"}';
    die();
}

function _blunderAndDie($reason = null)
{
    http_response_code(HttpStatus::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo ($reason === null)
        ? '{"error":"Server Error"}'
        : '{"error":"Server Error","reason":"' . $reason . '"}';
    die();
}

__run($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

?>
```

Perhaps this is the way it is? but it would be nice to have a splash screen that just says nothing to see here or something because most of the functions are done behind the scene.

Comment: The "Bad Request" error comes from within `_blameAndDie`, and that gets called at the end of `__run`. So whatever `$requestedModule` contains at that point (we don't know, because you did not tell us what URL you requested - make a debug output of the value at that point and check) does not appear to be contained in the `$modules` array.

Comment: Are requesting just the root URL, `/`, when this error occurs? A request URI `/foo` would lead to $requestedModule containing `foo` - but `/` would mean, it will contain an empty string only. And there is no element in the $modules array, that has only the empty string as value.

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry I am a total noob when it comes to this type of stuff. I wouldn't even know where to begin or what to write in to make a debug output for the requestedModule. But I do agree and understand I need to put a log somewhere so it can tell me what's broken.

Comment: Put a `var_dump($requestedModule);` after the line where the variable gets its value assigned, and see what that gets you.